# ADCS two tier PKI

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

Planning a two tier ADCS PKI infrastructure as follows:

```
              ORCA
   ____________|____________
  |            |            |
 SCA1         SCA2        SCA3
one.int      two.int    three.int
```

Where `ORCA` is an offline root CA, and `SCA1..SCA3` are subordinate CAs where each subordinate CA belongs to to a **completely different domain/forest with no trust or knowledge of one another** (`one.int`, `two.int`, `three.int`)

Now bearing in mind this is ADCS the *ideal* scenario is that the `ORCA` is configured with a LDAP URL for CRLs as well as a HTTP URL. Domain clients would then get the `ORCA`'s CRL from `LDAP` and non-domain clients would get it from the HTTP location, presumably a server running IIS or something.

However, this is a problem when multiple completely separate domains all use the same root - when the `ORCA` is configured it asks for a distinguished name and any issued CRLs with a LDAP URL in it will contain *exactly* that distinguished name.

So if we set the `ORCA`'s DN to `DC=one,DC=int` all CRLs issued by `ORCA` will contain `LDAP://<lots of stuff that don't matter>,DC=one,DC=int`. So now the clients from `two.int` and `three.int` would be trying to go over to `one.int` to get the CRL from LDAP there - yet they don't even know of the existence of the other domains/forests.

And if we try to take an `ORCA` CRL that contains `LDAP://...,Dc=one,DC=int` and manually publish it to `two.int` ... I'll get an error that `one.int` was not found.

We *could* remove all `LDAP` URLs from the `ORCA` CRL and only have a HTTP URL there, but the (other) advantage that publishing to LDAP gives is "automatic" redundancy and load balancing (in the sense that you never have a domain with a single DC). Giving a HTTP URL would mean that we would need a web server cluster to ensure high availability at the very least, but it also means a construct would look somewhat like this:

```
              ORCA
               |
          IIS CLORCA
   ____________|____________
  |            |            |
 SCA1         SCA2        SCA3
one.int      two.int    three.int
IIS CL1      IIS CL2     IIS CL3
```

Where each of the `IIS CL`s are IIS clusters: `IIS CLORCA` just the CRL for `ORCA` (and runs OCSP?), `IIS CL1` hosts the CRL + delta for `SCA1` and runs OCSP, etc etc...

Of course on the side of the `SCA1..SCA3` you *could* combine the CA role with the IIS role but would you really want to do that? That's a rubbish idea from a security point of view and increases the attack surface of the CA itself.

Of course in this construct each subordinate CA would publish to LDAP, but all of the domains have clients that are not part of the domain either so HTTP URL is required and makes no sense to have a single server serving serving the CRL/delta + OCSP. If that server happens to be offline when a non-domain client tries to validate a certificate - like it will happen at least once a month with Windows Updates -, the client will receive no reply from OSCP nor be able to download a CRL and therefore fail to validate the certificate. Hence the reason for IIS clusters on each individual domain.

Yet ... this feels over the top. I wanted to get people's opinions bearing in mind that the purpose of this is for a **production** environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with HTTP-only URLs. The only benefit with LDAP is redundancy and nothing else. Also, redundancy is orginized only between global catalogs, not all domain controllers.

HTTP supports `E-tag` and `Max-Age` headers. And Windows CryptoAPI client (at least) supports them to improve revocation checking experience. You can check my blog post on this subject in details: [Designing CRL Distribution Points and Authority Information Access locations](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/designing-crl-distribution-points-and-authority-information-access-locations.aspx)

You mentioned security risk when CRLs are hosted on a common IIS. There is no much security risk as long as IIS owners have possession of existence of all three forests. Also, IIS will make CRL separation by creating a separate web site for each forest. The only thing is they share -- same hardware at web server. Nothing else. In cloud solutions it is pretty common, when you share same hardware with other customers you are not aware of. domain part in URLs will be unique, you can purchase enough IP addresses to make websites completely irrelated.

> one.int is now able to ask the OCSP that's domain agnostic to validate a cert from two.int

one.int is able to ask the OCSP only if one.int gets a certtificate from two.int. And it doesn't matter if CRLs are hosted on a common web server or separate web servers. I don't clearly understand the security/privacy issue if revocation information is accessible from internet.

Comment: Thx for the answer, the blog is really useful. But I feel like it doesn't answer a lot of my (albeit indirect) questions: as it is presented it sounds like you're saying my 2nd diagram is the way to go. That implies 4 clusters for web servers and even if we assume 2 nodes per cluster that's 8 machines total. Feels like *a lot*. Now I can see that as a way of reducing this we can either have the subordinate CAs issuing their CRLs to the domain agnostic IIS cluster at the top (although I feel like this breaks security because `one.int` can find out which certificates were revoked on `two.int`)

Comment: Or another option is to remove the top cluster and use some DNS trickery: set the URL as something like `http://pkiserv/<something>` where `pkiserv` is *not* a FQDN and each individual domain's DNS lists a separate address for `pkiserv` - you're on `one.int`? Then `pkiserv` resolves to 10.0.0.1. `two.int?` then 10.0.0.2... etc Feels like a cheap trick with a lot of moving parts that can go wrong, but on the other hand 8 machines for 1 root and 3 subordinate CAs feels excessive (excluding the actual CAs ofc)

Comment: `I feel like this breaks security because one.int can find out which certificates were revoked on two.int` -- CRL doesn't include any sensitive data, so they barely break any security. CRLs only include serial numbers. You can't recover actual revoked certificate just from serial number. I would recommend a common IIS cluster with load balancing.

Comment: Breaks security in the sense that you now have one IIS (cluster) hosting CRLs for 3 domains that are meant to know nothing about one another. It doesn't mean security at a PKI level but, to an extent at least, removes the separation layer between the domains. Assuming that an OCSP would also be installed, `one.int` is now able to ask the OCSP that's domain agnostic to validate a cert from `two.int` - and it would get a reply! Maybe breaking security is not the best way to describe it, but removes a layer of separation that exists between the domains.

Comment: Also please in the name of anyone that reads your blog at work, can you *please* remove the link to Tera Patrick's website from the blog post above? Being completely oblivious as to whom Tera Patrick is I just learned the hard way -- seeing it for myself. And this while at work. Not nice.

Comment: Ok, the link is removed. It was originally added just for fun.

Comment: Yeah I get that but... look at your audience. Put a link to a nice picture of her instead (read, with clothes on), don't mind that at all. Anyway, I'm still not sure whether a single IIS cluster that hosts the CRL/CRT/delta for root + sub1 + sub2 + sub3 is better or if it's best for 1 IIS cluster for CRL/CRT for roo, 1 IIS cluster for CRL/CRL/delta for sub1 ... same for sub2 ...same for sub3... Thoughts?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: @Crypt32 Looking at the second diagram which includes ORCA IIS. What about updating the CDP & AIA URLs of the root each time you issue a different subordinate CA. For example when signing and issuing one.int Subordinate CA update the CDP & AIA URLs on ORCA to match that forest. When signing and issuing two.int Subordinate CA once again update the CDP & AIA URLs on ORCA to match that forest CDP/AIA and so on. Making sure to store those CDP & AIA URLs in a data store/text file for future re-use when renewing the Subordinate CA. This way you could get away with no ORCA IIS?